# Verilog: access a variable bits in a register

Tags: verilog

I want to get the variable bits in a register in each clock cycle.
The code as shown below can't work , I know that the problem is **get_bits** is not a constant,
but I don't know how to fix it. Does anybody know how to solve it?

```
    input [423:0]A;
    input [5:0] get_bits;
    output reg[423:0] B;

    
    
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn)begin
        if(!rstn)begin
            B<=0;
        end
        else
           B<=A[423:get_bits];
    end
```

`

Answer (score -1):

A logical right shift would be the equivalent of what you're trying to do with the variable slicing of `A` since the upper most bits of `B` would be 0 when `get_bits` is anything greater than 0:

```
B <= A >> get_bits;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when **get_bits** becomes larger, would it be a problem when synthesizing?

Comment: If you mean if you grow `get_bits` to more than 6 bits, then it does become bigger but the shift should scale linearly with the number of bits in `A` and `B` and logarithmically as `get_bits` with the number of bits  (if using a barrel shifter). The only way I can see to make it more efficient is if you don't move the bits of `A` wrt the bits in `B` (ie, bit 423 of `A` is always 423 of `B` no matter what `get_bits` is); that way you can just use `get_bits` to pass through a mask. The value of `get_bits` doesn't matter.